# Can anyone help identify the name of the white vessel in this photo w/the masts and funnel?

Tags: military, identification, naval, ships, names

[image: unidentified White hulled vessel, possibly in Boston area in the 1940s.The harbor tug is named IWANA and it was in service in Boston up until 1942. What is the name of the mystery white vessel?]

Unidentified White hulled vessel, possibly in the Boston area in the 1940s. The harbor tug is named IWANA and it was in service in Boston up until 1942. What is the name of the mystery white vessel? I’m curious if it possible it was a naval training vessel or a USCG revenue cutter. There are sailors on board with white uniforms and it is an American flagged vessel.

Comment: Yes, those buildings in the background are in [South Boston](https://www.bostonherald.com/2021/09/21/south-boston-power-plant-developers-get-ready-for-demolition-insisting-theyve-learned-from-past-issues/).

Comment: Looks like the Mayflower ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Mayflower_(PY-1) ) to me.  For: the shape of the deck, the placement of the portholes.  Against: most photos of the Mayflower show gaffs on the masts, and your pic does not.  But contra-against: google images of the Mayflower show many photos without.

Comment: Per the Wikipedia, it was in private hands from 1931 until July of 1942, so that gives a smallish window of time. Beautiful ship.

Comment: Thank you very much for these very interesting new leads. After reviewing the photos on Wikipedia, I also agree that this is the vessel USS Mayflower. The painted name on the stern also matches the amount of letters required to spell “Mayflower”. I had initially thought the name may have started with the letter “M”. Thank you very much for helping to solve the identity of this mystery ship. She has had quite some interesting historical figures onboard during its time as the presidential yacht.

Comment: It would appear that at least portions of the USMC band are aboard.  In the vicinity of the aft awning, when you blow-up the photo, you can make out instruments and Marine chevrons and visored caps.  With all the sailors wearing whites, Navy officers would be wearing white blouses, so the guys in the dark blouses with white trousers must be Marines.

Comment: Also appears to be flying the Presidential flag circa 1902-1916 (no stars).  Here's a shot of Mayflower with same. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_the_President_of_the_United_States#/media/File:USS_Mayflower_naval_review.jpg

Comment: @DaveMose - Since nobody posted an actual answer for you to accept, could you do so? Otherwise this is going to look to the system like an unanswered question.

Answer (score 6):

On reading the question I had the hunch, "looks like a US Presidential yacht", and googled "presidental yachts of the united states" and found a [page](https://megayachtnews.com/2021/01/5-u-s-presidential-yachts-from-the-20th-century/) with a photo that looked very much like the OP's picture, naming it as the [USS Mayflower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Mayflower_(PY-1)).  The overall appearance of the ship seemed to match, especially the placement of portholes.

Following R. Leonard's suggestion to look at blow-ups of the photo, I can almost read the name on the stern as "Mayflower", and see overall match with trustable pictures of the Mayflower, such as [this](http://www.navsource.org/archives/12/12130126.jpg) and [that](http://www.navsource.org/archives/12/12130133.jpg).

Answer (score 3):

After carefully reviewing all the helpful information provided by the other members, I agree that this photograph is of the presidential yacht USS Mayflower. Thank you all very much for your time and input.

Comment: Please note you can click on the checkmark appearing alongside the answer you agree with, selecting this as the 'accepted' answer.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, I was not aware of that I’m still learning.